# Split an array of Bytes previously read from a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, split

I have a recursive function, which takes as an argument an array of Bytes (read from a file) and then tries to split it into two parts for recursion calls.

The file format is for example like this:

```
word1 word2
word3 word4
   ....
word97 word98
word99 word100
```

So, to read it I use this code:

```
byte[] content = new byte[(int) file.length()];
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
fileInputStream.read(content);
```

But then I would like to Split the content array into two parts that each would represent the half of the original file. For example if the original file contains four lines, then the firstHalf array would contain the first two lines and the secondHalf array the last two lines of the original file.

I used this:

```
int halfTheLengthOfContent = (int) Math.ceil(content.length / 2.0);
firstHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(content, 0, halfTheLengthOfContent)
and 

secondHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(content, halfTheLengthOfContent + 1, content.length)
```

But it doesn't work since the resulting arrays don't correspond to what I want.
What I want is that the firstHalf array would contain the same content as if I've done this (with file1 this time containing the first half of the content of the original file and file2 the second half of it):

```
byte[] firstHalf = new byte[(int) file1.length()];
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file1);
fileInputStream.read(firstHalf);
```

and

```
byte[] secondHalf = new byte[(int) file2.length()];
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file2);
fileInputStream.read(secondHalf);
```

For example if the original file is this:

```
word1 word2
word3 word4
word5 word6
word7 word8
```

Then file1 is:

```
word1 word2
word3 word4
```

and file2 is this:

```
word5 word6
word7 word8
```

Could you please help me ?

Comment: what is `halfTheLengthOfContent`?

Comment: You need to keep trying to `read` until you have read all the bytes. Calling it once may or may not read the entire file, this is why it returns an `int`.

Comment: Two things: 1. you talk "lines" which are sequence of characters but you read bytes; there is a contradiction here; 2. why not use `ByteBuffer`s instead? Specifically the result of `FileChannel.map()`? This would allow _not_ to copy the contents over and over

Comment: @jhamon I updated my question, halfTheLengthOfContent is the half of the legth of my array

Comment: and what do you mean in `the resulting arrays don't correspond to what I want`

Comment: @jhamon you can see my updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of "bytes" and "lines" do not work well together.

Bytes are the core elements of a file, there may be a single byte per character. There may be two.

Splitting the `byte[]` that contains the entire file into two even portions is very unlikely to result in splitting into two `byte[]` containing the same number of lines. It is unlikely the split will even be on a linebreak, much more likely in the middle of a word.

What you need is to read the file as *lines* and manipulate them. For example:

```
final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path", "to", "file"));
final int middle = lines.size() / 2;
final List<String> firstHalf = lines.subList(0, middle);
final List<String> secondHalf = lines.subList(middle, lines.size());
```

If the file has `4` lines then `middle` will be `2`. The first half will contain lines `0, 1` and the second half will contain lines `2, 3`. Remember that a `List` is zero-indexed and `sublist` excludes the upper bound.

With an odd number of lines the second half will contain the extra element.